# SQL Server Backup Solution - Cleaning Up Dropped Databases

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

I'm just wondering how people who use Olas (fantastic) SQL Server Backup Solution deal with dropped databases.

The CleanupTime and CleanupMode parameters only operate on databases that currently exist on the instance, so dropped DBs persist on the file system until they're manually removed. Not such a big deal in small environments but something that needs attention in larger ones.

There doesn't appear to be a way to handle dropped DBs via the solution. Possible a new feature option?

Comment: How often are you dropping databases, that you need to automate deleting their remaining backup files?

Comment: We set up separate job to delete all files from backup folder older than a month.

Comment: We have tenancies where developers can create and drop databases as they please in their Dev environments, hence the requirement to clean up their backups. Sounds like a PowerShell script is the way to go to clean up these files, thanks for the replies.